# how to multiply two columns in gridview asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have gridview i which 4 columns i want to multiply rate to quantity to get total i do not how to do this kindly help me, please. here is code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  
                onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
              >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="cbGvProd" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="200px">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbQty" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbRate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="tbAmount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetGrid();
    }
    public void SetGrid()
    {

        DataTable tdTemp = new DataTable("TSno");
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("TDc");
        tdTemp.Columns.Add(dc);

        for (int a = 0; a <= 24; a++)
        {
            tdTemp.Rows.Add(a);
        }

        tdTemp.AcceptChanges();


        GridView1.DataSource = tdTemp;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            int qty = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].ToString());
            int rate= Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].ToString());

            int total=qty * rate;
            GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text = total.ToString();

        }
    }
```

Comment: [`RowDataBound`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx) fires **for each row**. So from the provided `GridViewRowEventArgs` you can access the Row, check the type, and set the values as needed.

Comment: so you got errors or it doesn't work at all or ?

Comment: @faizan try my answer it will 100% work for you but replace `Quantity` & `Price` with your `DataSet or DataTable` column name.

Answer (score 3):

Add a template field to get total, no need to do calculations on `RowDataBound`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblProductTotal" runat="server" 
        Text='<%# ((Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Quantity")))*(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Price"))))%>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Replace `Quantity` and `Price` with the column what your are using, means from dataset or datatable

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Now that your answer is useful, I have undone the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example using jQuery. Have a look at the code below and understand how it works then make changes to your application

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class GridTwo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<OrderLineItem> lineItems = new List<OrderLineItem>();
        lineItems.Add(new OrderLineItem { Price = 10.00M, Quantity = 0, ItemTotal = 0.00M });
        lineItems.Add(new OrderLineItem { Price = 100.00M, Quantity = 0, ItemTotal = 0.00M });
        lineItems.Add(new OrderLineItem { Price = 5.00M, Quantity = 0, ItemTotal = 0.00M });

        GridView1.DataSource = lineItems;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

public class OrderLineItem
{
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemTotal { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            $(".QuantityClass").on('change keyup paste', function () {

                //Ctrl+Shift+J in Google Chrome to bring up the console which allows you to debug javascript
                debugger;

                var textBox = this;
                var quantity = $(textBox).val();
                var tableRows = $(textBox).parent().parent().children();

                if (quantity != "") {
                    var price = tableRows[0].children[0].innerHTML;

                    var itemTotal = price * quantity;

                    tableRows[2].children[0].innerHTML = itemTotal;
                }
                else
                    tableRows[2].children[0].innerHTML = "";
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Price")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" CssClass="QuantityClass" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Quantity")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Total">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblItemTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Output:**

[image: Calculating two gridview columns client side]